# Trying to add a wp block and update the post content using PHP (wp_post_update)

Tags: php, wp-update-post

I'm looking to write some PHP code that will be capable of looping through all of a certain custom post type and adding a specific block to the post_content, and then updating the post.

For testing, I'm looking for a specific test post, parsing the blocks, and then trying to add a block to the end of the blocks array and then updating. Right now I have 2 issues

1. it adds the block twice to the end, its successful in adding to the page and saving, but it is happening twice
2. the innerblocks are not appearing, I'm adding 2 simple blocks as the innerblocks to the new $sidebarBlock but these innerblocks are not working. Do I need to some how serialize these as well?

I have tried to serialize_blocks() the 2 blocks that I'm inserting as the $sidebarBlock's innerblocks, but this did not work for me either.

Thank you for the help,

```
   $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'sort_order'=> 'DESC',
            'sort_column' => 'post_date',
            'post_type' => 'lorem-cpt-name'
        )
    );

    foreach($posts as $post) {
        // Looking for test post for local development..
        if ($post->ID === 27390)  {
            // Get all Blocks from the test post
            $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content ); 

            // We want to move several 'content' blocks inside a new $sidebarBlock, 
            which is declared below
            // add a couple content blocks to sidebar blocks array
            $sidebarInnerContentBlocks = [];
            array_push($sidebarInnerContentBlocks, $blocks[8]);
            array_push($sidebarInnerContentBlocks, $blocks[12]);

            // sidebar block, with 2 innerblocks added
            $sidebarBlock = Array (
                'blockName' => 'lorem-blocks/loremblockname',
                'attrs' => Array(
                    'align' => 'full',
                ),
                'innerBlocks' => $sidebarInnerContentBlocks,
                'innerHTML' => '',
                'innerContent' => Array(
                    0 =>'',
                    1 => '',
                    2 => '',
                )
            );

            // add new sidebar block to array of blocks
            $newBlocks = $blocks;
            array_push($newBlocks, $sidebarBlock);

            // new post content with sidebar block
            $newContent = serialize_blocks($newBlocks);

            // Save post (this adds the block twice to the page)
            $updated_post = array(
                'ID' => 27390,
                'post_content' => $newContent,
            );
            wp_update_post($updated_post);
        }
    }
```